# Many to many relationship and creating new records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A and B have a many-to-many relationship. In B's view I have a form to create a new B, with a new name and a new A (or many) association.

For example:

Create New B

Name:
A:

The same thing will be done when creating a new A. How am I to do this? And what does the controller/view/model look like?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when two table have a many-to-many relationship between each other, a join table is required since databases don't scale well horizontally.

First create your join table:

```
class AsBs< ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :as_bs do |t|
      t.integer :as_id
      t.integer :bs_id
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your models:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs, through: :as_bs
end


class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :as, through: as_bs
end
```

Start up your Rails console and see how you can interact and access the associated data in your DB.

Now to create a record here is what you should do in your AsBsController:

```
  def create
      @asbs = AsBs.find_or_create_by(as_id : params[:as_id], bs_is: params[bs_id]

  end
```

then save the record.

Comment: i have created a has many through relationship. however, i cant find anywhere that shows me what to do in my controller/view once i've made the models

Comment: would i even need a has many through relationship or can I do something like this? has_many :as belongs_to :b and has_many :bs belongs_to :a.

Comment: This answer doesn't have anything to do with creating new records. Does anyone have an answer to the question?

Comment: But it has something to do with many to many relationship. Take a look at my edit, that's how you create a record that has many to many relationship